# ReactJS: Unable to create Protect route for private screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jwt

On the **client-side** (React) I have a protected route that can only be accessed when the user is logged in.

In the **back-end** (Node.js, Express) I am using JWT & storing it in cookies - access token, and refresh token to authenticate the user. Access token gets expired every 30 seconds and refresh token is used to recreate access token.

What I want to do is to create a protected route for login user, by checking if the accesToken cookie and refreshtoken cookie is present or not, following is the code:

**Auth.js**

```
import axios from "axios";
import Cookies from "universal-cookie";
const cookies = new Cookies();

axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
class Auth {
  constructor() {
    this.authenticated = false;
  }

  isAuthenticated() {
    const accessToken = cookies.get("authSession");
    const refreshToken = cookies.get("refreshTokenID");

    if (!accessToken && !refreshToken) {
      return (this.authenticated = false);
    }

    if (accessToken && refreshToken) {
      return (this.authenticated = true);
    }

    if (!accessToken && refreshToken) {
      axios
        .post("/api/auth/refresh", {
          withCredentials: true,
        })
        .then(function (res) {
          console.log(res.data);
          // window.location.reload();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error.response);
        });
    }
  }
}

export default new Auth();
```

**ProtectedRoutes.js**

```
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";
import Auth from "./Auth";

const ProtectedRoutes = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  console.log("", Auth.isAuthenticated());

  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        Auth.isAuthenticated() ? (
          <Component {...props} />
        ) : (
          <Redirect to="/loginRegister" />
        )
      }
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoutes;
```

Everything is working fine I am able to log in, cookies are getting expired and recreated after every 30 seconds. Except when the access token gets expired and recreated, `Auth.isAuthenticated()` returns `undefined`. It returns `true` for only the first 30s (i.e. only until the first access cookie is not expired) but when I try to refresh my private page it gets returned back to loginRegister page
[image]

cookies are also present:
[image]

### UPDATE

I forgot to add my loginHandler and Privatescreen Route:

**Route**

```
import React from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import LoginRegisterScreen from "../../screens/LoginRegisterScreen/LoginRegisterScreen";
import ProtectedRoutes from "../Protect/ProtectedRoutes";
import PrivateScreen from "../../screens/PrivateScreen/PrivateScreen";

const Body = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <ProtectedRoutes exact path="/" component={PrivateScreen} />
        <Route exact path="/loginRegister" component={LoginRegisterScreen} />

      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};

export default Body;
```

**loginHandler** inside my **loginRegisterScreen.js**

```
const loginHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Login hander called");

    const config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    };

    try {
      await axios.post(
        "/api/auth/login",
        {
          email: loginEmail,
          password: loginPassword,
        },
        config
      );
      history.push("/");
    } catch (error) {
      setLoginError(error.response.data.error);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setLoginError("");
      }, 5000);
    }
  };
```

### UPDATE 2

It turns out I am still logged in, if I enter my private URL manually (i.e. `http://localhost:3000/`)inside the browser it is allowing me to access it, it's just, whenever my cookie gets expired `Auth.isAuthenticated()` gets `undefined` and I am pushed back to `/loginRegister` route. What should I do to make it `true` instead of `undefined`.

### UPDATE 3

Adding images for better understanding:

1. Immediately after I log in, my protect route comes into cation and the private screen is opened.
   [image]
2. After 30 sec when my access token gets expired, If I refresh the page, I pushed back to `/loginRegister` route because some how it is taking `Auth.isAuthenticated()` undefined.
   [image]
3. It is only when I type URL manually again and enter, It goes to private route:
   [image]

### UPDATE 4

Getting error undefined
[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Auth.js you don't return anything after claiming a new accessToken. You can just return true there like below;

```
...
 if (!accessToken && refreshToken) {
      axios
        .post("/api/auth/refresh", {
          withCredentials: true,
        })
        .then(function (res) {
          console.log(res.data);
          return (this.authenticated = true); // <-- this is a new piece of code here
          // window.location.reload();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.log(error.response);
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I tried `return (this.authenticated = true)` but I don't know why it is still showing `undefined`, It is only when I type URL manually, it returns `return (this.authenticated = true)` . I have updated the question with images for a better understanding of what is happening.

Comment: I think you need to debug `isAuthenticated`. If it is still undefined, it either goes in catch block or does not meet any of the if conditions,`isAuthentucated` is undefined when it does not return anything

Comment: @AnkushDogra, instead of `console.log(error.response);` can you just log `console.log(error);` in caatch block?

Comment: After logging I got `TypeError: this is undefined` you were right it is going to catch block,